# Launcher sometimes doesn't show with the mouse

Tags: unity, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 Unity and I am getting more and more convinced by the concept of unity. My launcher is set to hide when covered by a window and to show up when the mouse pointer hid the left.

However, once in a while when my mouse pointer hits the left nothing happens. Tipping two times the super button (unfortunately) displaying a windows logo the launcher is back to work. Any way to solve the problem or to hunt down the issue? I tried all possible settings in dconf editor, compiz config manager and whatsoever.

Comment: I still get this problem occasionally with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Since you have compiz config try changing the behavior.

CompizConfig Settings Manager> choose Ubuntu Unity Plugin> under Behaviour Tab choose Edge Reveal Timeout to 1 . Change Hide Launcher to Autohide.

Answer (score 1):

Use CompizConfig and make sure your KDE compatibility plugin is enabled.